# How to run a bash script via Cron

Tags: bash, cron

I have seen other questions that are similar but I can't find any real information on how to figure out the proper way to run a Bash script via Crontab. The `.sh` file is located in the user directory (in my case `serverpilot`).

The script is trying to copy the contents of the `apps` folder and send to my S3 bucket. The script works perfectly when run with `sh backupS3.sh` from the terminal but no joy via Cron. I've seen people reference PATH variables and the like but no idea where to even begin!

/backupS3.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Started backing to S3'
date +'%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
aws s3 sync /apps s3://bucketname
date +'%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
echo 'Finished backing to S3'
```

crontab

```
*/10 * * * * /backupS3.sh >> backupS3.log
```

Can anyone point me at anything obvious I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: I've added 2>&1 on to the end of the cron command and now I am getting something in the log file:

`/bin/sh: 1: /backupS3.sh: not found`

Comment: You say it's not working, but what's actually happening?

Comment: Sorry @JordonPhillips the script isn't running I believe as the sync never happens and the echo statements aren't printed to the log

Comment: I should point out that it **is** creating the log file but that the log file remains empty

Comment: Your script is a `sh` script, but running it with `bash` is harmless. The opposite generally does not hold. Either way, you should understand the difference before it jumps up and bites you. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash

Comment: Also, this isn't really a programming question; serverfault would be a better choice in the future.

Comment: What's the full path to `backupS3.sh`?

Comment: Point taken @MarkReed, if it's possible for it to be moved that would be great, if not next time I'll have a look over there. Thanks.

Comment: @will Based on comments below, it's `/srv/users/serverpilot/backupS3.sh`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In pathnames, the leading `/` doesn't mean "home directory"; it always refers to the root of the file system, no matter who you're logged in as.  You need to use the actual full, absolute path to the script (e.g. `/home/serverpilot/backupS3.sh`).  If the crontab belongs to the same user whose home directory holds the script, you can use `"$HOME"/backupS3.sh` and the system will fill in their home directory path for you.  Or, even more simply, just use `./backupS3.sh`, since cron jobs start with their working directory equal to their owner's home directory.

If that doesn't work, then either what you mean by "user directory" is not the same as the POSIX concept of "home directory", or the script is not executable (which you can fix by running the command `chmod +x backupS3.sh` once).

If you're not sure what the full path is, just run the `pwd` command while you're in the same directory that holds the script, and put the output, followed by a slash, in front of the script name.

Comment: Thanks, where would I run that `chmod` command? As a one-off in the terminal?

Comment: Yes, it just has to be run once.

Comment: Many thanks. Incidentally the `aws s3 sync /apps s3://bucketname` line within the script itself, will that know where to look or will that need to be the full server path also? Thanks again.

Comment: If the directory is `/apps`, great.  If it's `apps` under the user's home directory, then that also needs to be `"$HOME"/apps`.

Comment: When Cron runs a job, it starts in your home driectory. Maybe all you need is `./backupS3.sh`

Comment: Many thanks @MarkReed, I'm now receiving the following in my log `/srv/users/serverpilot/backupS3.sh: 4: /srv/users/serverpilot/backupS3.sh: aws: not found` Not sure if this is still saying it can't find the script or it's a problem with using the AWS CLI?

Comment: The `aws` command is not in the cron job's `$PATH`.  You'll need to specify the full path to it as well (which you can get with `which aws`).

Comment: Thanks @tripleee I think I did try that initially.

Comment: Obviously `/srv/serverpilot` is not the invoking user's home directory; but this answer sort of assumes that the script exists in your home directory, in which case the answer could be simpler.

Comment: @tripleee I suspect it's more that the attempt with the `./` path was before the `chmod`.

Comment: This answer is very helpful and has helped me get the script running. I'm now running into an AWS credentials error but I think that's due to configuring AWS originally as the root user

Comment: Now working perfectly. Thanks all for your superb help.

Answer (score 12):

I've had the same problem where log file was created empty and the only way to see what is going on was to add `2>&1` at the end of the cron job.

`*/10 * * * * /home/users/me/backupS3.sh >> /home/users/me/backupS3.log 2>&1`

If anybody wonders what `2>&1` actually mean here is a short explanation:

> 2 - refers to a file descriptor used to identify `stderr`
>
> 1 - refers to a file descriptor used to identify `stdout`

So `2>&1` basically translates to: Redirect `stderr`to`stdout`

Comment: You could skip the `2>&1` part by using `&>> /home/users/me/backupS3.log` where `&>>` would redirect all outbound file descriptors to the log file, not just 1/`stdout`.

Answer (score 8):

First, change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`, next use the full path to the script (also .sh isn't needed in the file name)

```
*/10 * * * * /home/users/me/backupS3.sh >> /home/users/me/backupS3.log
```

Comment: Thank you. When you say use the fullpath, I'm not sure where to point that to? I've added the Crontab to the `serverpilot` user (I also have access to the root of the server but thought it was preferable to login as serverpilot). I know the full server path to it, should I use that?

Comment: The `bash` hint is a red herring; your script currently does not contain any Bash-specific constructs.

Comment: Thanks for the info @triplee

Comment: @tripleee red herring?  It's additional and constructive since the user is posting this as a "bash question"  No need for a down vote, as the path was the issue.

Comment: The advice to change the shebang is incorrect; it simply does not help solve the problem.

Comment: @triplee then by your logic, after you give the advice (use full path), any additional help is incorrect.  I'm afraid this goes against every principal of helping.  Perhaps the problem is you stopped reading the answer when you got to the part you didn't like.

Comment: In fact, I read the entire answer, and it would be fine if you removed the part which is incorrect. There are many situations where that advice *would* help, but this isn't one of them. Recommending it anyway looks like [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) to me, which I do think is based on poor principles (incidentally, not *"principals").*